# PHP merge arrays by value and merge it's sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I thought I have some understanding of arrays. But it looks like I have no understanding. Or my head don't want to work. I have arrays:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 1
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1436821440000,12
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 2
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1437562620000,24
                    )
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 3
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1437080040000,10
                    )
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 1
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1437082860000,1
                    )
            )
    )

 [4] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 3
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1437081840000,9
                    )
            )
    )
```

And here is what I want to achieve:

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 1
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1436821440000,12
                        [1] => 1437082860000,1
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 2
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1437562620000,24
                    )
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [key] => Person 3
        [values] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1437080040000,10
                        [1] => 1437081840000,9
                    )
            )
    )
```

How could I remove duplicates and merge data?

Answer (score 1):

The sample input doesn't offer any variation in the data contained in the deept subarrays, so I'll demonstrate the utility of my snippet by adding a little more complexity in the data.

Effectively, each time a new `key` is encountered, you declare a new row containing the `key` element and a `values` element with an empty array.  To identify that `key` as "encountered", the new row is assigned to the result array using the `key` value as the first level key.

Now that the `values` subarray is guaranteed to be declared, an inner loop will comb through the deeper arrays and push one or more (all) deep values into the respective `values` subarray -- in a flat fashion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2Zqgc))

```
$array = [
    ['key' => 'Person 1', 'values' => [['1436821440000,12']]],
    ['key' => 'Person 2', 'values' => [['1437562620000,24']]],
    ['key' => 'Person 3', 'values' => [['1437080040000,10']]],
    ['key' => 'Person 1', 'values' => [['1437082860000,1'], ['1437082860000,2', '1437082860000,3']]],
    ['key' => 'Person 3', 'values' => [['1437081840000,9']]],
];

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['key']])) {
        $result[$row['key']] = ['key' => $row['key'], 'values' => []];
    }
    foreach ($row['values'] as $values) {
        array_push($result[$row['key']]['values'], ...$values);
    }
}
var_export(
    array_values($result)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'Person 1',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '1436821440000,12',
      1 => '1437082860000,1',
      2 => '1437082860000,2',
      3 => '1437082860000,3',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'Person 2',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '1437562620000,24',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'key' => 'Person 3',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '1437080040000,10',
      1 => '1437081840000,9',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $sub_arr) 
{
  $result_arr = array_merge($result_arr, $sub_arr);
  $result_arr = array_unique($result_arr);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but unfortunately this won't work the way that you expect it to. This would completely get rid of `Person 2` and would also result in the inner array values only using the last array value.

Comment: Yes, Ohgodwhy is right. And I'm getting "array to string conversion: error.